# Update kernel issues

Tags: update-manager, 23.04

[Better screenshot of error messages.  This message is the same for all 6.2 Kernels.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Cn2I.png)emphasized textMy OS name is Ubuntu 23.04.  My Kernel Version is Linux 5.19.0-40-generic.  I am unable to update my Kernel beyond that.  I constantly get errors..  What must I do?

[image: My usual error messages.]

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu!  Can you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1491293/edit) your question giving us more details about the errors you are seeing with copy and pasted errors.  Without the errors that you are seeing we can only guess.  Please help us help you!  Thank you!

Comment: Is there some way that it will let me post the screenshot of them?

Comment: @LarryCase Done!

Comment: Where did you get the source package rtl88x2bu-5.8.7.1, and what hardware does it support? The 6.2 kernel is failing to build that module.  Can you boot (grub selection) a 6.2 kernel in recovery mode?

Comment: rtl88x2bu-5.8.7.1. is a wifi adapter driver.  I cannot boot any 6.2 kernel

Comment: `rtl88x2bu-5.8.7.1` is a driver and not a WiFi adapter.  What is the hardware of your system that you are trying to install this on?

Comment: I wrote that it was an adapter driver.  The adapter works.  My system hardware is: Lenovo ThinkCentre M82.  It is an old one.   The reason that I like Linux is the fact that it adds new life to old computers.

Comment: Stumblebee, how did you get my screenshot to come up?

Comment: My bad!  You have it listed twice in your comments. Please remove any conflicting comments.  Also, please add any more details to your question and not in the comments.  One other thing, while I am looking at the [specs for your system](https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/withdrawnbook/M82.pdf) it is not showing any WiFi chipsets or cards.  This could have been an after market card then.  As far as making an image come up click on the image that looks like a mountain with a moon above the edit box.

Comment: It is an aftermarket dongle that I Purchased at Micro Center.  I can't find its brand name.  It does work.

Comment: I removed the WIFI driver.  It updates.